# How to add a descriptive text to Html.ActionLink() url's

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Given the typical Controller/Action/Id routing in mvc, looking to add a descriptive text so 
the url's are of the type

```
 mySite.com/home/page/myarg/the-title-of-the-page-etc.
```

this is similar to SO where they're of the form

```
 stackoverflow.com/questions/928349234/the-text-of-the-question-etc.
```

while this can be easily done with

```
  Html.ActionLink(LinkText, "Page", new { id = "myArg" } ) + "/" + myUrlText
```

Looking for any existing extensions which might be available which hopefully strip out non-alphanumeric characters etc. etc. before rolling out my own

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really want to append text to your ActionLink like that. You can accomplish what you want with Routing. Add a new route to your Global.asax RegisterRoutes method, above your Default route, like so:

```
routes.MapRoute("Page", "home/page/{id}/{title}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Page", id = UrlParameter.Optional, title = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Then you set-up your ActionLink like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("SomeText", "Page", new { controller = "Home", id = b.Key, title = Model.Title})
```

Comment: This is good, but I prefer this overload of the `ActionLink` method: `@Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "Controller", "Action", new { title = item.Title }, null)`.

Comment: thanks, do you know of any helper methods which make the title "url-friendly", don't want to be caught with tail end since it's user generated text !

Comment: I would write my own url-friendly helper extension to remove special characters and replace spaces with dashs. Then just call it on the title parameter like so `@Html.ActionLink(Model.Title, "Home", "Page", new
{
   id = Model.Key,
   title = Model.Title.FriendlyString()
}, null)`.